# How do I loop a css animation with multiple keyframe definitions?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

### The Issue

I have two css keyframe animations which I am running on a single element:

```
.fade-bg {
  animation-name: fade-bg-1, fade-bg-2;
  animation-delay: 0, 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

The animations are defined as such:

```
@keyframes fade-bg-1 {

  from {
      opacity: 0;
      background-image: url(image-1.jpg);
  }

  50% {
      opacity: 1;
      background-image: url(image-1.jpg);
  }

  to {
      opacity: 0;
      background-image: url(image-1.jpg);
  }

}

@keyframes fade-bg-2 { /* Same as fade-bg-1 only with image-2.jpg  */ }
```

The above works but when it gets to the second animation, it keeps repeating only that animation and does not loop back to `fade-bg-1`.

I've tried many different combinations of `animation-direction` but to no avail.

### The Question

How do I make it so that the animation returns to `fade-bg-1` and repeats itself?

### The Example

<kbd>[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qfwjg8k5/1/)</kbd>

Comment: I added [a bug for the CSS animation spec](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1726) about this.

Comment: LMAO you problem is my solution XD, well kind of I want something to fade in and then stay on screen while looping animation 2, but I imagine it should be able to the same. Thanks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without javascript I don't think you can. However you can achieve the same effect using a single keyframe animation.

```
.fade-bg {
  animation-name: fade-bg;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: forward;
}


@keyframes fade-bg {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url('image-1.jpg');
    }

    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url('image-1.jpg');
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url('image-1.jpg');
    }

    51% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url('image-2.jpg');
    }

    75% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url('image-2.jpg');
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url('image-2.jpg');
    }
}
```

<kbd>[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/181wzf9w/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Great! Why doesn't it work as expected with multiple animations?

Comment: This does not really answer the question but as long as no one else comes along with a better css only answer I'll accept yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible with just css, but if you set up a setInterval method in JS cleverly, you could probably simulate the same thing by splitting the class into two.

```
var index = 1;

function switchBackground() {
   if (index == 1) {
      //this switches to  the first background
      var div = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
      div.className = "fade-bg-1";
      index = 0;
   }
   else {
      //this switches to  the second background
      var div = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
      div.className = "fade-bg-2";
      index = 1;
   }
}

setInterval(switchBackground(), 6000);
```

With .fade-bg-1 and .fade-bg-2 being the two animation classes.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavinmarkee/p8hpn912/) if you want to play with it.

Comment: I should have pointed out that I did not want to use javascript for this one. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but we'll see if someone else can come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question almost 6 years ago, much has changed but no real solution with pure css.

The closest I could come up with was using a pseudo element to apply the second animation to.

### Possible Solution:

Use a pseudo element like `::after` and apply the second animation to it.

### Code:

```css
.animation--fade-bg, .animation--fade-bg::after {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

 .animation--fade-bg::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;

  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.animation--fade-bg-1 {
  animation-name: fade-bg-1;

}

.animation--fade-bg::after {
  animation-name: fade-bg-2;
}


@keyframes fade-bg-1 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sRnvs0K.jpg');
  }
    
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sRnvs0K.jpg');
  }   
     
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sRnvs0K.jpg');
  }
}

@keyframes fade-bg-2 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/wL4RT1w.jpg');
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/wL4RT1w.jpg');
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/wL4RT1w.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation--fade-bg animation--fade-bg-1"></div>
```