# How can I use JavaScript to infinitely reload some content after a 30 second delay each time?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

The following is some simplified code. The original code is a CSS3 keyframe animation. What I'm trying to do is infinitely loop my animation, but this doesn't seem to be possible using just CSS. So I am trying to reload the content and thus re-trigger the start of the animation. I have managed to do this once using setTimeout, but I need this to be infinite, after another 30 seconds I need it to reload and then again and again and so on.

I have these basic divs with ids and classes

```
<div id="main-container" class="main-container loaded">
  <div id="image-1" class="img img-1"></div>
  <div id="image-2" class="img img-2"></div>
</div>
```

I wrote this basic function that will reload the content after a 30 second delay, this gives the animation enough tome to reach it's end.

```
function refreshDiv(){
 var container = document.getElementById("main-container");
 var content = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML= content;
}

setTimeout(refreshDiv, 30000);
```

This works well, after the 30 second animation has run it replaces the main-containers content and so the animations can run again, but then after 30 seconds I need this to run again. I need this to run infinitely.

Comment: Did you try setinterval instead ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Comment: Thank you so much! setInterval worked perfectly. I wonder if it will eventually cause a problem because of minor differences in the speed of the keyframe animations on different hardware, but this is good for now. I'm surprised there isn't a way to loop keyframe animation sequences natively in CSS3. Seems strange we need to revert to JavaScript to do this.

Comment: You can loop keyframes though, you just need to set the animation iteration count to infinite => `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`. You can also read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385367/7071152 as an example, and you can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count